# Jira is not opened on crash (Jira - Fabric integration)

Tags: ios, jira, crashlytics, google-fabric

I did a full setup process for Fabric Jira integration, and confirmed it from the Fabric test page by pressing send test. Test issues are getting opened in my Jira project just fine. However, I forced crash in my app, and I see it in Fabric portal, but Jira didn't get created.

If anyone ran into this problem and has some insight on it, please help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Firebase and Fabric here. This can be caused by a couple of different things. Notifications into JIRA or any other service hook are done on a one-off basis per issue. Similar crashes are grouped into issues.

1) If the test issue is being created, then the first step would be to cause a new type of crash, one that hasn't occurred before in your app. Try causing a crash on a different button for example and that should do the trick.

2) If you've caused a brand new issue, check the impact level setting that you've set on the integration. For a new issue only if the impact level 1 is set to 1 in the integration would the notification be triggered.

Comment: and If the test issue is NOT being created ?